# EXCEL: Index Match Max date Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, max, match

This might have been solved already, but I am really struggling for days now... I am working on a client list. Multiple staff were in charge of different follow up for each client. However we are trying to allocate a unique staff to each client. We decided that the staff who did the last follow up would be in charge of the client. Therefore I need for each client (ID) line by line to see the max value according to (Date of follow up) and match with the correct staff (staff who did the follow up). What I should find is the column H, done manually in the example below, based on the last follow up. All the index match, with max value I tried only show for all clients CW3 as it is the last follow up for all clients.

[image: Click on the table to see the columns details before]

*I cannot upload images yet*

Comment: Would your date in follow up always be sorted like you show here?

Comment: Yes it would, it is an extraction from a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I used in `D2`:

[image]

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A=A2),C:C)
```

Also, it's always better to be more specific about ranges instead of whole column references.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, but unfortunately the result is #N/A. What the first "2" in your formula refers to?

Comment: The working of this formula is as follows; `LOOKUP()` will try to find the value "2", however the lookup array can never return that value. Only `TRUE` or `FALSE` (see the 2nd parameter). Where if `TRUE` means the same as 1. Because we can't find the lookup-value it will return the position of the last value of 1, hence it should return the last value from column c where the ID from column A:A is the same as `A2`. To me this works absolutely fine and doesn't even need CSE entering. @LegalCentre

Comment: Got it! The issue was to replace the "2" by the actual column #  as they are not matching with the simplified table made here. Thank you!

Comment: @LegalCentre, cool. Don't forget that if it has answered your question you can tick the checkmark to the left of the question to close the thread. Though I doubt that you need to replace the "2", rather replace the column references to the columns you need looking at.

Answer (score 0):

If you have <kbd>Excel365</kbd> then it would be easier for you to get desired result. Use below formula-

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER($B$2:$C$8,$A$2:$A$8=A2,""),1,-1),1,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that, however I do not have Excel365, so I do not have the function "FILTER". With a different version, would you have a suggestion?